# Unable to start spark thrift server in google-cloud-dataproc

Tags: apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I am having difficulties in starting the thrift server for spark sql in port 10010 in google-cloud dataproc cluster, It fails with the following error, Can anyone help please ?, I tried changing the port number still no luck.

sudo -u spark HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT=10010 /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh

Here is the log:

16/11/30 23:47:16 INFO org.apache.hive.service.AbstractService: Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is started.
16/11/30 23:47:16 INFO org.apache.hive.service.AbstractService: Service:HiveServer2 is started.
16/11/30 23:47:16 ERROR org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService: Error starting HiveServer2: could not start ThriftBinaryCLIService
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10002.
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:109)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:91)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.(TServerSocket.java:87)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.HiveAuthFactory.getServerSocket(HiveAuthFactory.java:241)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftBinaryCLIService.run(ThriftBinaryCLIService.java:66)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/30 23:47:16 INFO org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2: Shutting down HiveServer2
16/11/30 23:47:16 INFO org.apache.hive.service.AbstractService: Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is stopped.
16/11/30 23:47:16 INFO org.apache.hive.service.AbstractService: Service:OperationManager is stopped.
16/11/30 23:47:16 INFO org.apache.hive.service.AbstractService: Service:SessionManager is stopped.
16/11/30 23:47:16 INFO org.apache.hive.service.AbstractService: Service:CLIService is stopped.
16/11/30 23:47:16 INFO org.apache.hive.service.AbstractService: Service:HiveServer2 is stopped

Comment: It works as of Q2 2022, I tested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why that did not work, but I would recommend running
`apt-get install spark-thriftserver` instead.

The server is by default configured to come up on port 10002 (as it attempted to do in your case), but you can change that in `spark-env.sh`.

It's also worth noting that a Thrift Server with an AppMaster and executor can fill a small cluster, or be blocked out by another small Spark job.

Comment: Changing the HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT in spark-env.sh worked, Thanks.